# Сохранение изменений в структуре в файл

Tags: c++, алгоритм, файлы, структуры

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct work {
    string name;
    string secondName;
    string surname;
    string faculty;
    string pulpit;  //kafedra
    string position;
    int hours;
};
int startingMenu();
void editInformation(work &worker);
int menuEditInformation();
string editNameInformation(string a);
int main() {
    work worker;
    while (true) {
        switch (startingMenu())
        {
        case 4: 
            editInformation(worker);
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void editInformation(work &worker) {
    ifstream file1("list.txt");
    vector <work> vect;
    while (file1 >> worker.name >> worker.secondName >> worker.surname >> worker.faculty >> worker.pulpit >> worker.position >> worker.hours) {
        vect.push_back(worker);
    }
    file1.close();
    cout << "Enter the serial number of teacher, whose information you want to change:" << endl;
    int number = 0;
    cin >> number;
    number--;   //as user enters number (for ex. 2) but it has 1st index in vector
    cout << "Which information you want to change?" << endl;
    while (true) {
        switch (menuEditInformation())
        {
        case 1:
            vect[number].name = editNameInformation("name");
            break;
        case 2:
            vect[number].secondName = editNameInformation("second name");
            break;
        case 3:
            vect[number].surname = editNameInformation("surname");
            break;
        case 4:
            vect[number].faculty = editNameInformation("faculty");
            break;
        case 5:
            vect[number].pulpit = editNameInformation("pulpit");
            break;
        case 6:
            vect[number].position = editNameInformation("position");
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "Enter new amount of hours" << endl;
            cin >> vect[number].hours;
            break;
        case 8: return;
        }   
    }
    ofstream file2("list.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        file2 << vect[i].name<<" "<<vect[i].surname<<" "<<vect[i].faculty<<" "<<vect[i].pulpit<<" "<<vect[i].position<<" "<<vect[i].hours<< endl;
    }
    file2.close();
}
int menuEditInformation(){
    cout << "1 - name" << endl;
    cout << "2 - second name" << endl;
    cout << "3 - surname" << endl;
    cout << "4 - faculty" << endl;
    cout << "5 - pulpit" << endl;
    cout << "6 - position" << endl;
    cout << "7 - hours" << endl;
    cout << "8 - exit" << endl;
    int choise = 0;
    cin >> choise;
    return choise;
}
string editNameInformation(string a) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Enter new " << a << endl;
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << a << " successfully changed!" << endl;
    return str;
}
```

Задача данной части кода - считывание информации из файла в вектор структур, изменение необходимой информации и запись ее обратно в файл. Однако измененная информация, почему-то, не записывается. В чем ошибка?

Comment: STR?...........

Answer (score 2):

В функции `void editInformation(work &worker)` управление никогда не достигнет того места, где производится запись в файл, т.к. у Вас цикл выполняется бесконечно (либо до досрочного выхода из функции). А `break` (те что есть) действуют только на оператор `switch` внутри цикла.

Кстати, Вы принципиально игнорируете существование `default` случая во всех `switch`? Это может привести к неожиданным проблемам ;-) .

Comment: Vladimir, понял, спасибо. А насчёт default - забываю. Но сейчас добавлю